# How to elide type of temporary object in a variadic function call?

Tags: c++11, variadic-functions, template-argument-deduction, temporary-objects

When is it possible to elide types of temporaries passed into a variadic function template? Overload resolution doesn't seem to work. Consider this:

```
#include <vector>

struct option
{
    std::vector<int> to_wait;
    std::vector<int> to_set;
};


namespace fsm
{
    template <typename... Ts>
    void generic_wait(Ts... Args) {
        std::array<option, sizeof...(Ts)> hello = {{Args...}};
    }
}


int main()
{
    fsm::generic_wait(option{{2}, {3}}); // <-- This compiles
    // fsm::generic_wait({{2}, {3}}); // <-- This I would like to compile
}
```

This compiles only when I directly specify the temporary type. If I leave it off it stops working (C++11). Can I do something to make it work?

Comment: `generic_wait` takes arguments of arbitrary types. How is the compiler supposed to know what type the initializer list is supposed to actually initialize? How is it supposed to know that you meant `option` there? Nothing in the function signature mentions `option`

Comment: @IgorTandetnik: True, but the varargs are put into an std::array<option> container. I hoped the compiler would see through this. The problem is that I cannot specify the type of varargs or can I for this case?

Comment: Template parameter deduction doesn't look at the body of the function, only its signature. Anyway, the closest I managed to get is [this](https://godbolt.org/z/84nhPv61f). The size of the argument list is not constant (so can't store it in `std::array`, but can in `std::vector`) and the call site needs an extra pair of braces.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik: Right that makes sense. The initializer_list solution is pretty decent. But I wanted to make everything constexpr, so i guess that is not doable via initializer_lists and vectors :/